# Outdated libjpeg-turbo Library Contains known Security Flaw ( BETA) for react-native android app

Tags: android, react-native, security, mobile, libjpeg-turbo

I have a native mobile app with react (react-native) and I see the message above only for the android saying libjpeg-turbo library in versions prior to 2.0.2 is affected by so and so.

I did some research, could not find the library in the package.json, which led me to think this must be a dependency to some packages already in the app, but could not figure out where. And, also I don't remember installing it globally in my computer ever.

Is there anything I can do to install/update the libjpeg-turbo and if so where do I do it?

Please advise. Thank you in advance.